# Можно ли присвоить указателю адрес статического объекта на этапе компиляции?

Tags: c, указатели, компиляция

Можно ли присвоить указателю адрес статического объекта на этапе компиляции?

Пример такой, вот у меня етсть void* ptr и структура, которую я инициализирую на этапе компиляции, назовем ее buffer. Если я сделаю так ptr = &buffer; будет ли это присваивание выполнено на этапе компиляции. ТАк же, как мне на этапе компиляции заполнить массив указателей NULL'ами? Язык си.

Comment: Будет присвоен некоторый относительный адрес, который превратится в абсолютный при начальной загрузке программы в память. Заполнить массив указателей `NULL`ами - так же, как и массив `int`ов нулями :) - типа `void * p[N] = { NULL };`.

Comment: В любом случае будет настройка релокейшенов на этапе загрузки образа в память. Чего вы хотите добиться?

Comment: @Harry, а возможно ли в си, сделать функцию, которая будет заполнять массив определенными значениями на этапе компиляции? Иными словами, возможно ли в си явно указать компилятору, что функция должна работать на этапе компиляции?

Comment: @DenverToha, с функциями в Си это невозможно.

Comment: Нет, в C такое не предусмотрено.